# Add bins and other visual changes to already available graph generated through a Python library?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have generated a graph using a Python library (called "Fitter"). I would like to change the bin sizes on this histogram as well as do other visual changes but I couldn't get it to work by just applying values on the Fitter function.

Could someone kindly help ?

```
from fitter import Fitter
f = Fitter(data)
f.fit()
f.summary(Nbest=3, lw=3)

plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

[Histogram with Fitter function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIv8R.jpg)

Comment: Fitter has a bins parameter you could set - `f = Fitter(data, bins=20)`. What "other visual changes" do you need? The number of bins isn't really visual, it's pretty fundamental to the histogram!

Comment: @KenSyme many thanks. The code works well. Is there a way to include (color = black) to create a nice border for each binned distribution bar? I tried using the colour parameter into the function call, but doesn't work.

Comment: Is all you need the histogram? Or are you using fitter for other things?

Comment: I'm using Fitter to find the best statistical distribution function for my dataset. I'm interested in obtaining a histogram with a nicely fitted distribution curve. If there are any other graphs that I can generate via Fitter that's good to know too.